# queue.empty error when using search cursor

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I'm having trouble with an error message and can't seem to figure out the reason which, I'm sure is something simple. I have a bit of code listed below:

```
insertPts = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newFC, ( "FieldA", "FieldB"))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FC, ("FieldA", "FieldB"),""" "FieldA" IS NOT NULL """) as search:
    for row in search:
        num = row[0]
        rPtsNumber = randint(1, row[0])
        row[0] = rPtsNumber
        PTSid = int(row[1])
        for x in xrange (num):
            insertPts.insertRow((rPtsNumber, PTSid))
```

the error occurs in the line 'for row in search:'. I though it may be an issue with the where clause however, I tried creating a new feature class based on the where clause criteria and continue to get the error. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

This was a careless mistake on my part, I had been using the wrong FC variable in the search cursor. For this script I have too many variables with like names and confused 2 very important ones.

Comment: Good to know. Sometime's it's easier to assign your field as variables, that way should you need to re-use the script for different fields all you have to do is change the variable ex. `field1 = "NameField"` you would only have to change `"NameField"`